# How can I enforce default MSBuild configuration on referenced projects so they ignore overrides?

Tags: msbuild

My "entry point" project has explicit `x86` and `x64` platform configuration. All referenced projects are of `AnyCPU`. When I try to build my project with `/p:Configuration=Debug;Platform=x86` it fails on referenced projects with messages

> The OutputPath property is not set for this project.  Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid Configuration/Platform combination.  Configuration='Debug'  Platform='x86'`

Is there any way how I can enforce default configuration on referenced projects so they ignore my Configuration and Platform properies?

P.S. I'm building a single project, not solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that it does not possible. You need to configure your referenced projects for the provided configuration and platform as well.

Alternatively, you can build a solution instead of a single project. In this case you will need to create a solution configuration that fits your needs.

Comment: Agreed, configuration names must exist in each project built, even if using solution for compilation